# Codeigniter : URL issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have uploaded one site developed with codeigniter. and after applying the .htaccess, it is not working with index.php and working fine without index.php.

Please help me out to access the site with and without index.php in URL.

Comment: did you check apache log, maybe mod rewrite is not enabled?

Comment: will you please help me out to check on godaddy server for the same.?

Comment: Did you follow the [instructions](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) in the Codeigniter documentation?

Comment: yes. I have reviewed it. and I don't want to remove index.php from the URL. It is required for the system.

Comment: I misread your question, but upon further review I can't understand what you're asking at all. You say it works; then what is the problem? Here is another link that may help?: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Godaddy_Installaton_Tips

Comment: " it is now working with index.php and working fine without index.php." What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Please post your htaccess and some examples of urls that work, and that no longer work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you did not specific your apache version or config maybe you could try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

if it's not working then try this one

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```